# Set the React.FC state with values from a Promise in typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, promise, react-hooks, state

Im new in react, and i want to assign an array of objects to a React.FC state.
My api logic looks like this:

```
class LandApi {
    async getLands(): Promise<Land[]> {
        const response = await fetch('http://localhost:8080/api/lands', {
           method: 'GET',
           headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
        });

        return response.json();
    }
}
```

And i have this functional component:

```
 const MapLands: React.FC  = () =>
{
let [state, setState] = useState([])

useEffect(() => {
    LandApi.getLands().then((data) => {
        setState({
            landList: data  //the problem is here
        })
    })
})

return (
    <div>
        {
            //Map logic here
        }
    </div>
)
}
```

How can I 'put' that Land[] array in the functional components state, so i can map it later?

I'm pretty new to web programing as you can probably tell.

With sincere thanks,

Samuel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the JSON API is returning an array, then you almost had it!

First, add a type to your state, because typescript can't know what's in an empty array declared as `[]`.

```
let [state, setState] = useState<Land[]>([])
```

And then pass your result directly to `setState()`, with no object in between:

```
LandApi.getLands().then((data) => {
  setState(data)
})
```

Or more succinctly:

```
LandApi.getLands().then(setState)
```

This works because it's the same signature as the inline function that was there before. It takes one argument that is the new value.

Comment: Thank you a lot. Now this make sense to me.

Comment: Glad it helped and welcome to Stack Overflow! If an answer answers your question, don't forget to accept the answer by clicking the checkmark, as well as upvoting any helpful answers by clicking the up arrow, once you have enough reputation for upvoting.